# Оптимизация по времени задачи про страны, гражданства, образование и доход одноклассников

Tags: python, алгоритм

### Условие задачи

Кузя был очень удивлён, когда на десятилетие выпуска не приехала большая часть его одноклассников.

«Чему тут удивляться, разъехались по миру», — сказал ему один из пришедших одноклассников.

Кузя решил, что раз одноклассники не приехали на выпускной, то Кузя сам привезёт выпускной им. Правда для этого Кузе необходимо узнать, в какие страны они переехали.

Кузя знает, что каждая страна разрешает переезд на основе двух характеристик:

- Минимальный доход, необходимый для проживания;
- Обязательное наличие высшего образования.

Также Кузя знает, что некоторые страны разрешают переезд непосредственным детям своих граждан без необходимости удовлетворять описанным выше характеристикам.

Про каждого из уехавших одноклассников Кузя выяснил следующую информацию (мы сами не понимаем, где он всё это узнал):

- Величина дохода;
- Наличие высшего образования;
- Гражданство родителей.

Теперь Кузя просит вас, как лучшего игрока в GeoGuesser среди выпускников, выяснить страну, в которую переехал каждый из непришедших на выпускной одноклассников.

### Формат ввода

Первая строка содержит одно целое число *N* (*1 ≤ N ≤ 2·10<sup>5</sup>*) — количество стран, рассматриваемых для переезда.

Вторая строка содержит *N* целых чисел через пробел *a<sub>i</sub>* (*0 ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>*) — минимальный доход, необходимый для переезда в *i*-ю страну.

Третья строка содержит *N* целых чисел через пробел *b<sub>i</sub>* (*0 ≤ b<sub>i</sub> ≤ 1*) — *b<sub>i</sub>* равно *1*, если для
переезда в *i*-ю страну обязательно наличие высшего образования.

Четвертая строка содержит *N* целых чисел через пробел *c<sub>i</sub>* (*0 ≤ c<sub>i</sub> ≤ 1*) — *c<sub>i</sub>* равно *1*, если непосредственные дети граждан *i*-й страны могут переехать в *i*-ю страну, не удовлетворяя условиям на доход и высшее образование.

Страны нумеруются с *1* по *N* в порядке ввода.

Пятая строка содержит одно целое число *Q* (*1 ≤ Q ≤ 2·10<sup>5</sup>*) — количество одноклассников, не пришедших на выпускной.

Шестая строка содержит *Q* целых чисел через пробел *x<sub>j</sub>* (*0 ≤ x<sub>j</sub> ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>*) — доход *j*-го одноклассника.

Седьмая строка содержит *Q* целых чисел через пробел *y<sub>j</sub>* (*0 ≤ y<sub>j</sub> ≤ 1*) — *y<sub>j</sub>* равно *1*, если у *j*-го одноклассника есть высшее образование.

Восьмая строка содержит *Q* целых чисел через пробел *z<sub>j</sub>* (*0 ≤ z<sub>j</sub> ≤ N*) — гражданство родителей *j*-го одноклассника, заданное номером страны или *0*, если их гражданство
неизвестно.

Одноклассники нумеруются с *1* по *Q* в порядке ввода.

### Формат вывода

В единственной строке выведите *Q* целых чисел через пробел *t<sub>j</sub>* (*0 ≤ t<sub>j</sub> ≤ N*) — номер страны, которую выбрал для переезда *j*-й одноклассник.

Каждый одноклассник может выбрать только страну, в которую он имеет право переехать (согласно условиям).

В случае, если одноклассник может выбрать несколько стран для переезда, он выберет страну с наименьшим номером в списке (Кузя любезно отсортировал страны в порядке убывания привлекательности для переезда).

Если одноклассник не мог переехать ни в одну из описанных стран, выведите *0*.

Ссылка на задачу № 2: https://hsto.org/getpro/freelansim/allfiles/16/169/169389/Microsoft_Word_Document___kopiya__1_.pdf

```
def binary_search(tuples_countrys, fact_cash, n_country):
    if n_country == 1:
        hold = tuples_countrys[0]
        if hold[0] <= fact_cash:
            return tuples_countrys
        else:
            return []
    low = 0
    high = n_country - 1
    search_res = False
    guess = tuples_countrys[0]
    middle = 0
    while low <= high and not search_res:
        middle = (low + high) // 2  # отвечает за средний эллемент в массиве
        guess = tuples_countrys[middle]
        if guess[0] == fact_cash:
            search_res = True
        elif guess[0] > fact_cash:
            high = middle - 1
        else:
            low = middle + 1
    if middle == n - 1 and guess[0] <= fact_cash:
        return tuples_countrys
    while guess[0] <= fact_cash and middle < n_country - 1:
        middle += 1
        guess = tuples_countrys[middle]
    return tuples_countrys[:middle]


n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
c = list(map(int, input().split()))
q = int(input())
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
y = list(map(int, input().split()))
z = list(map(int, input().split()))

j = 0
output_country = [0] * q

tuples_country = []
i = 0
while i < n:
    tuples_country.append((a[i], b[i], i + 1))
    i += 1
tuples_country.sort()
hold_countrys = []
while j < q:
    if c[z[j] - 1] == 1:
        output_country[j] = z[j]
    hold_countrys.clear()
    hold_countrys.extend(binary_search(tuples_country, x[j], n))
    if len(hold_countrys) == 0:
        j += 1
        continue
    if y[j] == 1:
        hold_countrys.sort(key=lambda a: a[2])
        hold = hold_countrys[0]
        country = hold[2]
    else:
        hold_countrys.sort(key=lambda a: a[1])
        country = n
        hold = hold_countrys[0]
        if hold[1] == 1:
            j += 1
            continue
        for guess in hold_countrys:
            if guess[1] == 1:
                break
            if country > guess[2]:
                country = guess[2]
    if country < output_country[j] or output_country[j] == 0:
        output_country[j] = country



    j += 1

print(*output_country)
```

Пример ввода и вывода:

```
Ввод 
2 
10 9 
1 0 
0 1 
5 
0 0 11 10 9 
0 1 0 1 1 
2 1 0 0 0 

Вывод
2 0 2 1 2
```

Comment: добавьте условие своей задачи, ожидаемый ввод/вывод

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали:
Пример
Ввод
2
10 9
1 0
0 1
5
0 0 11 10 9
0 1 0 1 1
2 1 0 0 0
Вывод
2 0 2 1 2

Comment: Участок ввода данных принимает входные из примера и верно решает еще 10 тестов в контестере, но на 12 не успевает по времени (ограничение 4 секунды)

Comment: Проблема в чем у вас? По времени не проходит или решение неверное?

Comment: @tym32167 по времени не проходит, решает верно

Comment: а, время, вижу. Вам совет номер один тогда- если вам надо найти страну у которой граница для въезда в страну ниже чем доход у человека, то для такого поиска можно испольховать двоичный поиск вместо вашего линейного сейчас

Comment: также, если вам надо понять, если у страны, где гражданство родителей, разрешено по гражданству родителей переезжать - вам на надо перебирать для этого все страны, вы уже знаете страну родителей, у вас есть массив с нулями-единичками `c`, вам достаточно просто проверить там 1 или 0 по конкретному индексу в массиве

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за подсказку с двоичным поиском, читаю сейчас статью по данному поводу, пробую написать новый код, с Вашими комментариями.

Comment: @tym32167 столкнулся со следующей проблемой: перед бинарным поиском необходимо сделать сортировку стран, но после данной сортировки теряется порядковый номер страны для вывода. Как поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: Сортируйте для бинарного поиска кортежи вида "(название страны, порядковый номер)", они и отсортируются как вам нужно и их них можно извлечь и страну и её номер.

Comment: @CrazyElf понял, пошел учить, что такое кортежи)

Comment: @Mikle Ну это примерно неизменяемые списки )  Но в каких-то случаях они удобнее и быстрее списков.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я добавил кортежи и сделал по Вашему совету, но видимо надо еще чуть-чуть ускорить, потому что стала программа работать в 3 раза быстрее, но при новых тестах не хватает работоспособности на 100 милисекунд  быстрее

Comment: Занимательная задачка

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy готово!

Answer (score 7):

Как всегда, задачу нужно сначала решить, а потом программировать. Для каждого одноклассника делается один проход по странам в их списочном порядке, никакие сортировки и поиски не нужны.

Есть три условия: гражданство родителей, которое преобладает над всеми остальными, и равноправные имущественный и образовательный ценз. Таким образом в цикле по странам проверяем (гражданство ИЛИ образование И зарплата). На первой стране, удовлетворяющей условию, останавливаемся.

**UPD** Что можно оптимизировать?

Итак, для стран имеем массив *(bool гражданство, bool образование, int доход) [N] страны*, для одноклассников *(int страна, bool образование, int доход) [Q] одноклассники.* На выходе *страна [Q] резиденство*.

Тогда:

```
cтраны[0] = (false, false, 0) // UPD это чтобы лишние проверки не делать, когда родители - патриоты

а = cтраны[одноклассники[i].страна].гражданство ? одноклассники[i].страна : N + 1 // это первая оптимизация

j = 1 to a - 1:

    если (!cтраны[j].образование ИЛИ одноклассники[i].образование) И cтраны[j].доход <= одноклассники[i].доход:

        а = j, выход

резиденство[i] = а <= N ? а : 0
```

**Решение.**

Итак, для стран имеем массивы:

1. *(int образование, int доход)[N] страны* - это вторая и третья строки
2. *int[N] гражданство* - четвёртая строка
3. *(int страна, int доход)[N] всестраны*
4. *(int страна, int доход)[K] страныБЕЗобразования* (K <= N).

Для одноклассников:

1. *int[Q] острана*
2. *int[Q] ообразование*
3. *int[Q] одноклассники.*

На выходе *int[Q] резиденство*.

Тогда:

```
Отсортировать "страны" по возрастанию дохода

Пройти по масиву "страны" и для каждого элемента в поле "страна"
    записать наименьшую страну из всех элементов от начала и до данного.
    # Вот это самая фишка

Получить массив "всестраны"

Получить массив "страныБЕЗобразования"

гражданство[0] = 0 // UPD это чтобы лишние проверки не делать, когда родители - патриоты

для каждого одноклассника i:

    а = гражданство[острана[i]] == 1 ? острана[i] : N + 1

    если а > 1:

        b = N + 1

        если ообразование[i] == 1:

            b = "страна" от двоичного поиска первого элемента с подходящим доходом из "всестраны"

        иначе:
            b = "страна" от двоичного поиска первого элемента с подходящим доходом из "страныБЕЗобразования" 

        а = min(a, b)

    резиденство[i] = а <= N ? а : 0
```

Специалистов по языку (питонистов, питонщиков? питонцев? питоняшек? :-) ) прошу камнями не бросать, а поправить, если что:

```
import time
import sys
import array

class CountryRecord:
    def __init__(s,a,b,c):
        s.country=a
        s.income=b
        s.edu=c

def bs(sa,income):
    l=0
    r=len(sa)-1
    while l<r:
        m=(l+r)//2
        il=sa[m].income
        if il>income:
            if m>0:
                r=m-1
            else:
                return CountryRecord(N+1,0,N+1)
        elif il==income:
            return sa[m]
        else:
            if sa[m+1].income>income:
                return sa[m]
            if sa[m+1].income==income:
                return sa[m+1]
            else:
                l=m+1
    if l>r:
        return CountryRecord(N+1,0,N+1)
    else:
        return sa[l] if sa[l].income<=income else CountryRecord(N+1,0,N+1)

start_time = time.time()

sys.stdin = open("mc5.txt", "r") # fill it with input data, delete this line in prod

N = int(input())
a=list(map(int, input().split())) # country income limit
b=list(map(int, input().split())) # country education requirement 
c=array.array('i',[0])
c.extend(map(int, input().split())) # country citizenship requirement
Q = int(input())
mi=array.array('i',map(int, input().split())) # student income
me=array.array('i',map(int, input().split())) # student education
mc=array.array('i',map(int, input().split())) # student inherited citizenship

ca=list(map(CountryRecord, range(1,N+1), a, b))
ca.sort(key=lambda CountryRecord: CountryRecord.income)
ce=list(filter(lambda x: x.edu==0, ca))
least=N+1
for ica in ca:
    if ica.country<least:
        least=ica.country
    ica.edu=ica.country
    ica.country=least
least=N+1
for ice in ce:
    if ice.edu<least:
        least=ice.edu
    ice.edu=least

res=[]
for i in range(0,Q):
    cbc=mc[i] if c[mc[i]]==1 else N+1
    if cbc>1:
        b=bs(ca,mi[i]).country if me[i]==1 else bs(ce,mi[i]).edu
        cbc=min(cbc,b)
    res.append(cbc if cbc<=N else 0)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)) # delete this line in prod

print(*res)
```

**Решение без двоичного поиска**

@StanislavVolodarskiy подсказал, что можно поискать такой вариант.
Идея состоит в том, что списк студентов нужно тоже отсортировать по доходу и потом с каждым студентом двигаться (или не двигаться) по списку стран до нужного дохода. Сложность линейная.

```
import time
import sys
import array

class CountryRecord:
    def __init__(s,a,b,c):
        s.country=a
        s.income=b
        s.edu=c

class StudentRecord:
    def __init__(s,a,b):
        s.number=a
        s.income=b

start_time = time.time()

sys.stdin = open("mc5.txt", "r") # fill it with input data, delete this line in prod

N = int(input())
ci=list(map(int, input().split())) # country income limit
ce=list(map(int, input().split())) # country education requirement 
cc=array.array('i',[0])
cc.extend(map(int, input().split())) # country citizenship requirement
Q = int(input())
st=list(map(StudentRecord,range(1,Q+1),map(int, input().split()))) # student income
st.sort(key=lambda StudentRecord: StudentRecord.income)
me=array.array('i',map(int, input().split())) # student education
mc=array.array('i',map(int, input().split())) # student inherited citizenship

ca=list(map(CountryRecord,range(1,N+1),ci,ce))
ca.sort(key=lambda CountryRecord: CountryRecord.income)
ce=list(filter(lambda x: x.edu==0, ca))
least=N+1
for ica in ca:
    if ica.country<least:
        least=ica.country
    ica.edu=ica.country
    ica.country=least
least=N+1
for ice in ce:
    if ice.edu<least:
        least=ice.edu
    ice.edu=least
O=len(ce)

ia=0
ie=0
mo=array.array('i',range(0,Q))
for sti in st:
    i=sti.number-1
    cbc=mc[i] if cc[mc[i]]==1 else N+1
    income=sti.income
    if me[i]==1:
        while ia<N:
            if income>ca[ia].income:
                ia=ia+1
            else:
                b=ca[ia].country if income==ca[ia].income else (N+1 if ia==0 else ca[ia-1].country)
                break
        else:
            b=ca[N-1].country
    else:
        while ie<O:
            if income>ce[ie].income:
                ie=ie+1
            else:
                b=ce[ie].edu if income==ce[ie].income else (N+1 if ie==0 else ce[ie-1].edu)
                break
        else:
            b=ce[O-1].edu
    cbc=min(cbc,b)
    mo[i]=cbc if cbc<=N else 0

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)) # delete this line in prod

print(*mo)
```

**Дальнейшая оптимизация без сортировки стран (методом естественного отбора :-))**

```
import time
import sys
import array

class CountryRecord:
    def __init__(s,a,b):
        s.country=a
        s.income=b

class StudentRecord:
    def __init__(s,a,b):
        s.number=a
        s.income=b

start_time = time.time()

sys.stdin = open("mc5.txt", "r") # fill it with input data, delete this line in prod

N = int(input())
ci=tuple(map(int, input().split())) # country income limit
ce=tuple(map(int, input().split())) # country education requirement 
cc=array.array('i',[0])
cc.extend(map(int, input().split())) # country citizenship requirement
Q = int(input())
st=list(map(StudentRecord,range(1,Q+1),map(int, input().split()))) # student income
st.sort(key=lambda StudentRecord: StudentRecord.income)
me=tuple(map(int, input().split())) # student education
mc=tuple(map(int, input().split())) # student inherited citizenship

c1=[]
least1=10000000000 # since it's limited by statement
c0=[]
least0=10000000000
for i in range(N):
    if ci[i]<least1:
        least1=ci[i]
        c1.append(CountryRecord(i+1,ci[i]))
    if ce[i]==0 and ci[i]<least0:
        least0=ci[i]
        c0.append(CountryRecord(i+1,ci[i]))
Nl=N+1
c1.append(CountryRecord(Nl,0))
c0.append(CountryRecord(Nl,0))
O1=len(c1)
O0=len(c0)

i1=O1-1
i0=O0-1
c1l=c1[0].country
c0l=c0[0].country
mo=array.array('i',range(Q))
for sti in st:
    i=sti.number-1
    income=sti.income
    if me[i]==1:
        while i1>=0:
            if income>=c1[i1].income:
                i1=i1-1
            else:
                b=c1[i1+1].country
                break
        else:
            b=c1l
    else:
        while i0>=0:
            if income>=c0[i0].income:
                i0=i0-1
            else:
                b=c0[i0+1].country
                break
        else:
            b=c0l
    cbc=min(mc[i],b) if cc[mc[i]]==1 else b
    mo[i]=cbc if cbc<=N else 0

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)) # delete this line in prod

print(*mo)
```

Выигрыш по времени есть, но можно подумать над тем, как избавиться от второго списка стран без образовательного ценза.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147167/discussion-on-answer-by-rotabor-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 5):

Ответ большой, вот оглавление

- **Проблемы** - тут рассказывается почему сложность решения в вопросе *O(Q·N·logN)*.
- **Первое решение** - решение с двоичным поиском и сортировкой списка стран за *O((N + Q)·logN)*.
- **Второе решение** - тоже решение с двоичным поиском, но сортировка списка стран заменена на фильтрацию. Сложность *O(N + Q·logN)*.
- **Третье решение** - решение без двоичного поиска, и с сортировкой списка учеников. Сложность *O(N + Q·logQ)*. Самое короткое решение.

### Проблемы

`binary_search` ищет подходящее место в массиве стран за логарифм. Затем в цикле `while` он за линейное время поправляет решение так что бы включить все страны с доходом меньше или равным `fact_cash`. Если *N = 2 · 10<sup>5</sup>* двоичный поиск сделает семнадцать итераций. После чего цикл сделает, скажем, 100 тысяч итераций. Пример можно подобрать.

Понятно что отличная производительность дихотомии буквально тонет в ужасной производительности линейного поиска. В ту же копилку оператор `return` - он копирует кусок массива. Можно так сделать, что будут копироваться почти все элементы массива, а это опять линейная сложность.

Короче говоря, сложность `binary_search` не логарифмическая а линейная.

Подмассив из `binary_search` попадает в переменную `hold_countrys`, которая сортируется для извлечения минимума. Сложность операции *N·logN*. Искать минимум можно проще и быстрее.

И снова сложность двоичного поиска мажорируется другой операцией. Общая сложность решения - *O(Q·N·logN)*.

Есть ещё опечатка: вместо `n` должно быть написано `n_country`:

> ```
>     if middle == n - 1 and guess[0] <= fact_cash:
> ```

Опечатка ни на что не влияет, но лучше не писать код на верхнем уровне. Могут быть случайные заимствования глобальных переменных с последующей неприятной отладкой.

### Первое решение

Отложим в сторону родственников и образование, сосредоточимся на основной механике. По уровню дохода ученика требуется отобрать страны подходящие для эмиграции. Решается за логарифм двоичным поиском по списку стран, который предварительно упорядочен по доходам.
Из отобранных стран нужно выбрать страну с наименьшим номером. Сделать это надо быстро. Нет времени просматривать все подходящие страны.

Например:

> ```
>  страна   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>   доход  50  70  60  90  30  80  40  10  20
> ```

Сортируем по доходу:

> ```
>  страна   8   9   5   7   1   3   2   6   4
>   доход  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90
> ```

Какую страну выбрать с доходом *40*? Страны с подходящими доходами: *8*, *9*, *5*, *7*. Нам нужен минимальный номер: *5*.

Пробежимся по списку номеров стран и впишем минимумы:

> ```
>  страна    8   9   5   7   1   3   2   6   4
> минимум    8   8   5   5   1   1   1   1   1
>   доход   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90
> ```

При движении по списку стран текущий минимум зависит от дохода текущей страны и предыдущего минимума. Следовательно список минимумов номеров стран строится за линейное время.

Теперь имея доход мы можем за логарифм отыскать самую привлекательную страну.

Таких списков доходов нужно два. Первый для обладателей высшего образования, в нем все страны. Второй для кандидатов без высшего образования, в нём только страны с *b<sub>i</sub> = 0*.

Кроме проверки дохода надо проверить родителей. Проверка делается за константу.

В коде ниже `bsearch` отыскивает самую правую страну с доходом не превосходящим *x*. Если таких стран нет вовсе, возвращается *-1*.

`make_income_list` сортирует пары *[a<sub>i</sub>, i]*. После сортировки индекс страны заменяется на индекс минимальной подходящей страны (объяснения даны выше).

`main` читает данные, готовит списки доходов для образованных и для необразованных, в цикле перебирает учеников. Для каждого ученика подбираются страны-кандидаты по доходу и по родителям, выбирается лучшая страна.

Сложность: чтение данных - *O(N) + O(Q)*, подготовка списков доходов - *O(N·logN) + O(N)*, обработка учеников - *O(Q·logN)*, печать ответа - *O(Q)*.

После упрощения: *O((N + Q)·logN)*.

```
def bsearch(incomes, x):
    lo = -1
    hi = len(incomes)
    while lo + 1 < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if incomes[mid][0] <= x:
            lo = mid
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo


def make_income_list(seq):
    incomes = sorted(seq)
    if incomes:
        mini = incomes[0][1]
    for r in incomes:
        mini = min(mini, r[1])
        r[1] = mini
    return incomes


def main():
    input() # skip n
    a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    b = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    c = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

    input() # skip q
    x = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    y = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    z = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

    incomes = (
        make_income_list(
            [ai, i]
            for i, (ai, bi) in enumerate(zip(a, b), start=1)
            if bi == 0
        ),
        make_income_list(
            [ai, i]
            for i, ai in enumerate(a, start=1)
        )
    )

    answer = []
    for xj, yj, zj in zip(x, y, z):
        countries = []
        k = bsearch(incomes[yj], xj)
        if k != -1:
            countries.append(incomes[yj][k][1])
        if zj != 0 and c[zj - 1] == 1:
            countries.append(zj)
        answer.append(min(countries, default=0))
    print(*answer)


main()
```

### Второе решение

Введём понятие неинтересной страны. Страна *i<sub>2</sub>* неинтересна если существует *i<sub>1</sub>*: *i<sub>1</sub> < i<sub>2</sub>* и *a<sub>i<sub>1</sub></sub> ≤ a<sub>i<sub>2</sub></sub>*. Никто не поедет в страну *i<sub>2</sub>*, так как в списке до неё есть страна в которой требования к доходу ниже.

Например:

> ```
>  страна   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>   доход  50  70  60  90  30  80  40  10  20
> ```

Страны *2*, *3*, *4* неинтересны из-за первой страны. Последовательно пройдём по списку стран слева направо и удалим неинтересные. Останется последовательность убывающих доходов, которую не нужно сортировать (!):

> ```
>  страна   1   5   8
>   доход  50  30  10
> ```

Перевернём получившийся список и будем использовать в двоичном поиске как в первом варианте программы. Единственное что изменится в программе, функция `make_income_list`:

```
def make_income_list(seq):
    incomes = []
    for r in seq:
        if not incomes or incomes[-1][0] > r[0]:
            incomes.append(r)
    return incomes[::-1]
```

Сложность изменится в лучшую сторону: подготовка списков доходов была *O(N·logN) + O(N)*, а стала *O(N)*.

Сложность в целом: *O(N + Q·logN)*.

### Третье решение

Зная доход ученика, подходящую страну можно отыскать линейным поиском по списку стран. Годится первая страна с требуемым доходом не более дохода ученика.

Если доход следующего ученика меньше, то просматривать список стран с начала не нужно. Можно продолжить поиск со страны в которую уехал первый, более богатый, ученик.

Идея состоит в том чтобы отсортировать учеников по убыванию дохода и последовательно отыскивать им подходящие страны двигаясь слева направо по списку стран.

Процесс поиска делается два раза: для образованных и для необразованных учеников. Переменная *e* отвечает за образование.

В конец списка стран добавляется псевдострана в которую нельзя уехать. Это "часовой" который упрощает цикл по странам.

Обработка родителей не изменилась.

Сложность: чтение данных - *O(N) + O(Q)*, подготовка списка стран - *O(N)*, подготовка списка учеников - *O(Q·logQ)*, поиск стран по доходу *O(N + Q)*, печать ответа - *O(Q)*.

После упрощения: *O(N + Q·logQ)*.

```
input() # skip n
a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
b = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
c = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

q = int(input())
x = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
y = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
z = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

answer = [None] * q

for e in (0, 1):
    countries = [
        (ai, (i, ))
        for i, (ai, bi) in enumerate(zip(a, b), start=1)
        if bi <= e
    ]
    countries.append((0, ())) # sentinel
    it = iter(countries)

    students = reversed(sorted(
        (xj, zj, k)
        for k, (xj, yj, zj) in enumerate(zip(x, y, z))
        if yj == e
    ))
    ai, t = next(it)
    for (xj, zj, k) in students:
        targets = []
        while xj < ai:
            ai, t = next(it)
        targets.extend(t)
        if zj != 0 and c[zj - 1] == 1:
            targets.append(zj)
        answer[k] = min(targets, default=0)

print(*answer)
```

Comment: Не рассмотрен случай, когда в нескольких странах одинаковые требования по доходу. Может давать ошибку. У меня это обрабатывается в двоичном поиске, но есть второй вариант - в списке оставить один элемент с повторяющимся доходом и ему сопоставить наименьшую страну.

Comment: Двоичный поиск вернёт самую правую страну в этом случае. В этой стране вписан самый минимальный минимум. Автоматом получится верный ответ.

Comment: Не уверен на счёт самой правой, нужно подумать. Но, в любом случае, минимальная страна будет первой, и все остальные элементы с таким доходом будут иметь ту же страну. Да, ничего делать не нужно.

Comment: @rotabor, "минимальная страна будет первой" - это отличная идея, которая позволяет обойтись без сортировки стран по доходу. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, есть интересные варианты, но далеко не все они дадут выигрыш по времени.

Comment: Спасибо большое Всем, за разбор задачи, но к сожалению, я не могу ее протестировать больше, так как доступ к контесту закрыт. Могу ли я просто закрыть данный вопрос или обязательно необходимо выбрать того, кто решил?

Comment: @Mikle, закрывать не нужно. Задача интересна ещё многим людям. Её уже решили тремя разными способами и есть интересные вопросы по этим решениям. Я ещё не закончил свой ответ. За шесть дней вы получили семь плюсиков только на вопросе. Объявлен конкурс. Выбирать того кто решил не обязательно, хотя по этикету принято так делать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за информацию, тогда оставлю все как есть

Comment: Супер!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Поздравляю! Кроме алгоритма, код на Питоне - тоже важная составляющая.